# Populate data using server side (python)

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb

I am displaying a pie chart using python and javascript.

Here's my code:

```
function defectCode() {


    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'defect code');
    data.addColumn('number', 'affected');
    data.addRows([
      ['defect code 1', 518],
      ['defect code 2', 400],
      ['defect code 3', 188],
      ['defect code 4', 118],
    ]);

   
    var options = {title:'Top 4 Defect Code',
                   width:500,
                   height:500};

  
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('code_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

As of now, i have given data's as static as mentioned in code. Now i want to retrieve the data's from my mongodb database and display in web. I have created a collection and inserted the values in mongodb . How to populate in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to fetch the document you've saved in MongoDB

```
import pymongo

mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = mongo_client["db_name"]
db_collection = db["collection_name"]

query = { "id": 123 }

document = db_collection.find(query)

for item in document:
  print(item)
```

and then you can populate by replacing the static data with the item.

Hope this helps :)

Reference for Help: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_getstarted.asp

Official documentation for pymongo : https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html